# AWS API Gateway Not Connecting to Lambda Alias

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to connect an API Gateway build to my lambda which has versioned aliases.

This is the setup:

AWS Lambda

---

Lambda `functionName` Has two aliases, staging and production. Staging is pointing to $LATEST and production is pointing to the last stable version (let's say version 1).

API Gateway

---

The API has two stages, staging and production. Each stage is to be associated with a specific lambda alias. `funcName` is a stage variable added to each stage as either `staging` or `production`. The resources are setup as follows:

Resources:

```
    /route1
        ANY METHOD -> lambda function -> functionName:${stageVariables.funcName}
    /route2/{proxy+}
        ANY METHOD -> lambda function -> functionName:${stageVariables.funcName}
```

When I add these resources and methods AWS let's me know to manually update the lambda function's policies to allow the API to call them using the following script:

For route1:

```
aws lambda add-permission   
--function-name "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:account-id:function:functionName:staging"   
--source-arn "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:account-id:7aupeov6ak/*/*/route1"   
--principal apigateway.amazonaws.com   
--statement-id 30bdb347-9b5b-4eed-9221-d3d8de3e6def   
--action lambda:InvokeFunction
```

For route2

```
aws lambda add-permission   
--function-name "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:account-id:function:functionName:staging"   
--source-arn "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:account-id:7aupeov6ak/*/*/route2/*"   
--principal apigateway.amazonaws.com   
--statement-id 30bdb347-9b5b-4eed-9221-d3d8de3e6def   
--action lambda:InvokeFunction
```

Policy after CLI commands:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "30bdb347-9b5b-4eed-9221-d3d8de3e6def",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:account-id:function:functionName:staging",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:account-id:7aupeov6ak/*/*/route2/*"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "30bdb347-9b5b-4eed-9221-d3d8de3e6def",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:account-id:function:functionName:staging",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:account-id:7aupeov6ak/*/*/route2/*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The commands go through successfully, and the policies are added to the lambda alias, however, when I check triggers both are throwing the following error:

"The API with ID 7aupeov6ak doesn’t include a resource with path /route1 having an integration arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:account-id:function:functionName:staging on the ANY method."

I read both of these tutorials and it appears I've done everything correctly.

- https://www.contentstack.com/blog/tech-talk/deploying-aws-lambda-in-different-environments/
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-gateway-stage-variables-to-manage-lambda-functions/

Comment: did you ever get to the bottom of this? I am in a similar position except I am using terraform